# Convert "Tcl_Obj* const objv[]" to "char** argv"

Tags: c++11, tcl

I'm using Tcl 8.6 and I'm trying to do something like this to add functions to the tcl interpreter

```
Tcl_Interp* interp, 

void init() {
  interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
}

void add_tcl_function(char* cmd, function<int(int,char**)> F) {
    obj2argv* o2a = new obj2argv;

    auto lambda_proc = [&](
        ClientData cdata, 
        Tcl_Interp* interp, 
        int objc, 
        Tcl_Obj* const objv[])
    {
       o2a->set(objc, objv);
       F(objc, o2a->get_argv());
    };

    auto lamba_delete = [&](
      delete o2a;
    };

    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, cmd, lamda_proc, NULL, lamda_delete);
}
```

What I'm wondering is how to convert "Tcl_Obj* const objv[]" to "char** argv"?

I was thinking about creating a class:

```
class obj2argv {
    obj2argv();
    void set(int objc, Tcl_Obj* const objv[]);
    char** get_argv();
private: 
  //...
};
```

any ideas on how to implement set() and get_argv()?

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks.

```
obj2argv* o2a = new obj2argv;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're interfacing a function that's fundamentally working with `const char**` for arguments, you should register the function with `Tcl_CreateCommand` and let Tcl handle the mapping to strings for you. It already has all the mechanisms required.

---

More formally, you are dealing with a gluing function with this signature:

```c
typedef int (Tcl_CmdProc) (ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp,
        int argc, CONST84 char *argv[]);
```

The `CONST84` should be read as being plain `const` in all new code, and `ClientData` is a pointer-sized value that Tcl just hands around and never inspects (same as with your existing code).

---

If you are going to do the mapping yourself, `Tcl_GetString` takes a `Tcl_Obj*` and returns the `char*` representation of it. The representation should be usually treated as `const`; it simply isn't formally typed as such for historical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add some more information:

I gave up on using lambda's because when I added capture list it won't convert the lambda to a function pointer for some reason.  So I went with the traditional approach (see below).  EXCEPT: I still have not idea why the TCL document says

```
typedef int Tcl_CmdProc(
        ClientData clientData,
        Tcl_Interp *interp,
        int argc,
        const char *argv[]);
```

But the compiler requires this to compile:

```
typedef int Tcl_CmdProc(
        ClientData clientData,
        Tcl_Interp *interp,
        int argc,
        Tcl_Obj*  const* argv);
```

The Code:

```
int cmd_dispatch(
  ClientData   clientData,
  Tcl_Interp*  interp,
  int          argc,
  Tcl_Obj*  const* argv)
{
  function<int(int,char**)> F = *(function<int(int,char**)>*)clientData;

  return F(argc, (char**) argv);  // <= CAST DOESN'T SEEM RIGHT
}

void cmd_delete(ClientData clientData)
{

}

void add_tcl_function(const char* cmd, function<int(int,char**)> F) {

    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, cmd, cmd_dispatch, (void*)&F, cmd_delete);

}
```

VERSION 2:

```
struct cmd_data {
//Tcl_Interp*                interp,
  function<int(int,char**)>  F;
  int                        argc;
  char*                      argv[MAX_ARGS];
};

int cmd_dispatch(
  ClientData   clientData,
  Tcl_Interp*  interp,
  int          argc,
  Tcl_Obj*  const* objv)
{
  auto cmd_data1 = (struct cmd_data*) clientData;

  cmd_data1->argc = argc;
  for(int i=0; ((i < argc) && (i < MAX_ARGS)); i++) {
    cmd_data1->argv[i] = Tcl_GetString(objv[i]);
        // Who owns object returned by Tcl_GetString?
        //  memory leak? or invalid after return from function?
        // garbage collected by tcl interp? 
  }
  return cmd_data1->F(argc, cmd_data1->argv);
}

void cmd_delete(ClientData clientData)
{
  auto cmd_data1 = (struct cmd_data*) clientData;

  if (cmd_data1) {
    delete cmd_data1;
  }
}


void add_tcl_function(const char* cmd, function<int(int,char**)> F) {


    auto cmd_data1 = new struct cmd_data;
    cmd_data1->F = F;
    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, cmd, cmd_dispatch, (void*)cmd_data1, cmd_delete);

}


void init_tcl_commands() {
    auto lambda_hello = [&](int argc ,char** argv) -> int {
        cout << "HELLO WORLD!\n";
        return 0;
    };

    tcl_backend::add_tcl_function("hello", lambda_hello);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what TCL document you refer to, but the current docs for `Tcl_CreateObjCommand` have the signature mentioned that your compiler wants. The older signature is for `Tcl_CreateCommand`. (see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/CrtCommand.htm and http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/CrtObjCmd.htm )